# How do I make my VBox and Label resize according to texts in label in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

[image]

As you can see, my texts are constrained by `label`s. How do I make the `label` resize to exactly fit the text and also to resize the `VBox` and `GridPane` accordingly. I only want to resize vertically.

My FXML:

```
<VBox fx:id="body"
    alignment="TOP_CENTER"
    prefHeight="150"
    GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES"
    prefWidth="300"
    GridPane.columnIndex="0"
    GridPane.rowIndex="1" spacing="5">

    <Label alignment="CENTER" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" fx:id="word" maxWidth="268"/>
    <Pane prefHeight="10" VBox.vgrow="NEVER"/>
    <Label alignment="CENTER" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" wrapText="true" fx:id="meaning" maxWidth="268"  />
    <Label alignment="CENTER"  textAlignment="JUSTIFY" wrapText="true" fx:id="sentence" maxWidth="268" />

</VBox>
```

This `VBox` is inside the `GridPane`:

```
<GridPane fx:id="base"
      alignment="CENTER"
      prefHeight="210.0"
      maxWidth="310.0"
      stylesheets="@style.css"
      vgap="0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="sample.Controller">
...
```

**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example** as requested by @James_D

Main Class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
private Stage stage;
private StackPane stackPane;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    stage = primaryStage;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
    stackPane = new StackPane(root);
    Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);
    scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Controller Class:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{
    @FXML private Label label1;
    @FXML private Button changeLabel;
    private StringProperty labelString = new SimpleStringProperty();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        labelString.setValue("aasdasd sad asdasd asdasda");
        label1.textProperty().bind(labelString);

    }
    @FXML
    public void clicked(MouseEvent e){
        labelString.setValue("asdsadasd asdasdasd sfdgsfwoef fgtrhfgbdrgdf dfgdfivbjkfd gdfgidfjvdf gdfgjldkvbdf gjdilgjdfv dfgojdflkgdf ");
    }
}
```

sample.fxml:

```
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" maxHeight="Infinity">
<children>
    <VBox fx:id="body"
          alignment="CENTER"
          maxHeight="Infinity"
          GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES"
          prefWidth="300"
          GridPane.columnIndex="0"
          GridPane.rowIndex="1" spacing="5">

    <Label alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" wrapText="true" textAlignment="CENTER" fx:id="label1" maxWidth="268"/>
    <Button fx:id="changeLabel" text="Change" minWidth="50" onMouseClicked="#clicked" maxWidth="Infinity" />
    </VBox>
</children>
```

**Expectation:**
When I press 'Change' button, Everything should resize to just give enough space for text to be shown.

**Problem:**
When I press 'Change' button, UI remains same not showing the full text.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want the labels to grow horizontally, or do you want the text to wrap onto a new line?

Comment: @James_D My `Label` wraps into a new line given enough space. The problem is, `VBox` holding labels and `GridPane` isn't growing to show labels completely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want the text to wrap, the labels will need to be able to grow vertically. Add the attribute

```
maxHeight="Infinity"
```

to each label. You are also constraining the overall height of the `VBox` with `prefHeight="150"`; remove that attribute and let the `VBox` figure out its own height. Similarly, you probably want to remove the `prefHeight` attribute from the `GridPane`.

Comment: But it doesn't resize when I update my label in the run time. What is the manual way to set the height to auto?

Comment: Can you edit your question so that it becomes a [MCVE]. As long as the grid pane has enough room to resize, it should work.

Comment: It does work for the first time FXML loads up. But I use a thread to change the label during the run time and it doesn't resize in the runtime. And only after I restart the app, it will resize. So, what I want is a manual method to auto-resize to be added in my ActionListener.

Comment: I wanted something similar like `gridPane.setPrefHeight(auto);` (I know auto doesn't fit there but you know what I mean) so I can add this inside my listener event.

Comment: The equivalent would be `gridPane.setPrefHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE)`, but that is the default setting anyway. JavaFX uses a "top-down" layout, so the size of the grid pane is determined by its parent in the scene graph. Since you haven't shown the code where you actually use your grid pane anywhere (which is precisely why I asked you for a [MCVE]), there's no possible way to answer your question as it stands.

Comment: If the grid pane is the root of the scene, it will just take on the size of the scene. Try calling `Stage.sizeToScene()` after changing the content of the label.

Comment: Would have got there a lot quicker if you'd explained you wanted the window to resize...

Comment: Haha! Sorry about that. From next time, I will make sure I will provide MCVe from the start.